# Sqlite: How to update multiple values?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an SQLITE table with a column of integer values for example:

```
existing_rows = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
```

How to update some of the entries based on two arrays: from and to? Let's say

```
from = [1,3,5] 
to = [11,12,13]
```

the existing_rows after the operation should be:

```
[11,2,12,4,13,6,7,8,9,0]
```

Is it possible without creating an additional temporary table ?

Comment: Simply use look up tables and run an update join.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your column is named x and your table is named y and you only want a statement that does the update

```
UPDATE y 
SET x = CASE 
WHEN x = 1 THEN 11 
WHEN x = 3 THEN 12 
WHEN x = 5 THEN 13 
END 
WHERE x in (1,3,5)
```

Update:

Assuming your exclusion of temporary tables only means real tables and not table valued functions... caveat, your array values have to be provided as JSON

```
CREATE TABLE y (x INTEGER);
INSERT INTO y VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(0);
UPDATE y SET x = json_extract(tmp.value,'$.replacement') FROM json_each('[{"value":1,"replacement":11},{"value":3,"replacement":12},{"value":5,"replacement":13}]') tmp WHERE x = json_extract(tmp.value,'$.value');
SELECT * FROM y;
```

Comment: Sorry but that is not scalable. Plus it is hardcoded will work for this specific example but nothing else

Comment: sqlite itself does not feature arrays as in your question... but current versions have json support available ... see update if that works for you